# convert gregorian Date to hijri date is back wrong days

Tags: android, calendar, hijri

I want to convert from Gregorian to Hijri(Islamic) date and I use [this class](http://www.coderanch.com/t/534271/java/java/Gregorian-Hijri-Dates-Converter-JAVA)

the problem is islamic month's days is <29 , 30 , 29 , 30 else
but this class month's days is < 30, 29, 30, 29 else 
any body can help fix this?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

/**
 * Gregorian-Hijri Dates Converter
 * 
 * 
 * This Code is used to convert Gregorian dates to Hijri Dates 
 * 
 *
 */

public class DateHigri {

```
static double gmod(double n,double  m) {
    return ((n % m) + m) % m;
}

static double[] kuwaiticalendar(boolean adjust) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int adj=0;
    if(adjust){
        adj=0;
    }else{
        adj=1;
    }

    if (adjust) {
        int adjustmili = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * adj;
        long todaymili = today.getTimeInMillis() + adjustmili;
        today.setTimeInMillis(todaymili);
    }
    double day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    double  month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    double  year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    double  m = month + 1;
    double  y = year;
    if (m < 3) {
        y -= 1;
        m += 12;
    }

    double a = Math.floor(y / 100.);
    double b = 2 - a + Math.floor(a / 4.);

    if (y < 1583)
        b = 0;
    if (y == 1582) {
        if (m > 10)
            b = -10;
        if (m == 10) {
            b = 0;
            if (day > 4)
                b = -10;
        }
    }

    double jd = Math.floor(365.25 * (y + 4716)) + Math.floor(30.6001 * (m + 1)) + day
            + b - 1524;

    b = 0;
    if (jd > 2299160) {
        a = Math.floor((jd - 1867216.25) / 36524.25);
        b = 1 + a - Math.floor(a / 4.);
    }
    double bb = jd + b + 1524;
    double cc = Math.floor((bb - 122.1) / 365.25);
    double dd = Math.floor(365.25 * cc);
    double ee = Math.floor((bb - dd) / 30.6001);
    day = (bb - dd) - Math.floor(30.6001 * ee);
    month = ee - 1;
    if (ee > 13) {
        cc += 1;
        month = ee - 13;
    }
    year = cc - 4716;

    double wd = gmod(jd + 1, 7) + 1;

    double iyear = 10631. / 30.;
    double epochastro = 1948084;
    double epochcivil = 1948085;

    double shift1 = 8.01 / 60.;

    double z = jd - epochastro;
    double cyc = Math.floor(z / 10631.);
    z = z - 10631 * cyc;
    double j = Math.floor((z - shift1) / iyear);
    double iy = 30 * cyc + j;
    z = z - Math.floor(j * iyear + shift1);
    double im = Math.floor((z + 28.5001) / 29.5);
    if (im == 13)
        im = 12;
    double id = z - Math.floor(29.5001 * im - 29);

    double[]  myRes = new double[8];

    myRes[0] = day; // calculated day (CE)
    myRes[1] = month - 1; // calculated month (CE)
    myRes[2] = year; // calculated year (CE)
    myRes[3] = jd - 1; // julian day number
    myRes[4] = wd - 1; // weekday number
    myRes[5] = id; // islamic date
    myRes[6] = im - 1; // islamic month
    myRes[7] = iy; // islamic year

    return myRes;
}
static String writeIslamicDate() {
    String[] wdNames = {"Ahad", "Ithnin", "Thulatha", "Arbaa", "Khams",
            "Jumuah", "Sabt"};
    String[] iMonthNames = {"Muharram", "Safar", "Rabi'ul Awwal",
            "Rabi'ul Akhir", "Jumadal Ula", "Jumadal Akhira", "Rajab",
            "Sha'ban", "Ramadan", "Shawwal", "Dhul Qa'ada", "Dhul Hijja"};
    // This Value is used to give the correct day +- 1 day
    boolean dayTest=true;
    double[] iDate = kuwaiticalendar(dayTest);
    String outputIslamicDate = wdNames[(int) iDate[4]] + ", " + iDate[5] + " "
            + iMonthNames[(int) iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";

    return outputIslamicDate;
}
```

}

Comment: What about this alternative using [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A)? See this short [example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/b39fa253a6b7c4ab6f97).

Comment: By the way, I have never seen this order: 29, 30, 29, ... Only know it otherwise as documented [here](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/islam_tabcal.htm), Muharram is reported to always have 30 days based on tabular variants (first month of Hijri year). Your desired order seems to be wrong because it would result in a length of year one day less (than 354/355 days).

Comment: @MenoHochschild this change is in arabic calendar for Coordination Otherwise in orginal islamic date moharam is 29 and safar is 30

Comment: Would you please show any reference to this calendar variant ("arabic calendar for coordination") and its algorithm or rules? Then I can imagine to implement it in my library Time4A. And if your desired leap year pattern is irregular (following astronomy and/or visibility of New Moon) then you can edit a data table file for configuration already now in Time4A.

Comment: oh sorry i check again and see i was wrong :-/ sorry in persian calendar convert moharam is 29 :-| for exm in time.ir

Comment: well, Persian calendar is completely different (a solar calendar in contrast to lunar Hijri calendar), also implemented in Time4A. The month cycles of both calendars are different, too, not comparable. So Hijri Muharram can be mapped to any Persian month over a greater period of years.

Comment: tanks so much... i really was tired about match this dates... but yes you right they are different